# Help me to draw this table your please

Tags: tables

Could you help me to draw this table[image]

Comment: Show us what you have done so far, and ask about a specific problem. This way the community will be able to help you more.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  It's not exactly clear what aspects of the table you want.  Any decent introduction to LaTeX will help you make a table.  If there's some aspect of your resulting table that you're not pleased with, we'd be happy to take your minimal working example and fix that problem.